# Best practice for mysql database design

Tags: mysql, database

Suppose i have a form and I have to ask user some question. A sample question is like below.

> Do you work either at home or outside your home for pay?

and answers are

1. Yes
2. No
3. I do not want to answer

If user select **Yes** then i have to ask another question like

> Type of work?

answer are:

1. Full-time
2. Part-time
3. Other

Now if user select **Other** i have to show edittext for some text input

For this scenario  what is the best practice to design database to store the answers.
i am thinking 2 options

1. one column for the the answer[separated by ',' ]. Example: **Yes,full-time** or **Yes,other,some text** or **No**
2. three column for answer[each column contain a part of answer]. Example:

   [image]

Which option is the good practice??? If i have type of conditional question of depth 5/6/7 or more then how i store data in table. Is there any better approach or good practice for this type scenario. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

i think you should separate the questions :

1. you need to create id for each question and then add the answer
2. add column with related questions

something like this

```
date,user_id,question_id,answer,answer_position, related_question 
xxx   yyy     1             yes   1               5
```

This pattern more effective for analyzing.
and you will not be limited for future changes

Answer (score 0):

There are different approaches depending on the remainder of your questions-answers and the relationships.

Perhaps you'd like to try a single table such as:

```
id | questionid | order | text | moreinfo |
-----------------------------------------
1  |          1 |     1 |  Yes |        0 |
2  |          1 |     2 |   No |        0 |
3  |          2 |     1 |  Full time |  0 |
4  |          2 |     2 |  Part time |  0 |
5  |          2 |     3 |  Other     |  1 |
```

In this above example, I have included questionid.  This would refer to questions stored in another table, or possibly within this table, depending on how you may already have stored any other questions.  This is similar to the following.

```
id | parentid | order |        text       | moreinfo |
-----------------------------------------
1  |        0 |     1 | Are you working?  |        0 |
2  |        1 |     1 | Yes               |        0 |
3  |        1 |     2 | No                |        0 |
4  |        2 |     2 | Great! How much?  |        0 |
5  |        4 |     1 | Full time         |        0 |
6  |        4 |     2 | Part time         |        0 |
7  |        4 |     3 | Other             |        1 |
```

In this above example, I have included parentid to refer internally within this table to parent answers, that lead to secondary answers. This structure is conceptually similar and really only differs in the field name, and its philosophical meaning.

> If i have type of conditional question of depth 5/6/7 or more then
>   how i store data in table. Is there any better approach or good
>   practice for this type scenario. Thanks in advance.

The second table example itself can be nested 5/6/7/1000 times deep, because it's a self-referencing table.  You can add other fields as you need!

Please also read up on normalization database structure, it'll open your eyes and give you a lot more ideas.  Here's an example link:

http://www.guru99.com/database-normalization.html